"Unable to load the specified metadata resource" after building using dotnet build
After some conclusions, a more precise questions:
I have a .NET 4.0 project with Entity Framework v4 which uses an .edmx file. Let's call it EFProject and MyDB to the database accessed by Entity Framework.
This project is part of a solution that includes projects - some of them are new SDK projects files.
In the project file of the EFProject, I define the .edmx and Designer.cs files as EmbeddedResources:
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include=MyDB.edmx" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include=MyDB.Designer.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

In the app.config, I added to the MyDB connection string, the .edmx file:
<add name="MyDBConnectionString" 
     connectionString="metadata=res=://*/MyDB.edmx|res://MyDB.csdl|...."

When building the solution in VS or with CLI command:
dotnet build

the solution builds with no errors.
When I'm looking "into" the EFProject dll (decompiling using dotPeek), I can see the resources of the .edmx and designer.cs files, but I dont see any csdl files. Should I see these also ?
BUT: when executing the application (after building by using dotnet build) and reaching the EFProject - I'm getting an error
claiming:

Unable to load the specified metadata resource


The problem happens only after building using the cli command. When running it after building it using Visual Studio build, so errors thrown.

I've tried other options: to build the project also separately - but still - it doesn't work.
Any ideas how can I solve this?

Large parts of my answers are generated from this blog and concerning discussion thread.
The cause of this error is a missing or malformed Entity Framework connection string. In particular, the cause of this error is the metadata parameter of the connection string.
So in your connectionString=metadata=res=://*/MyDB.edmx|res://MyDB.csdl|.... that basic format is

res://: Indicates we're loading CSDL from a resource
*: The name of the assembly which contains the resource. In your case you're omitting the name by using *, which is common!
MyDb.edmx: The name of the resource itself

I'd ensure you're second connection string resource res://MyDb.csdl is properly calling an assembly version in this case.

Andrew thanks. I 've edited my questions, adding 2 enhancements

@GuyE, you're edits still shouldn't have changed anything from my response. You are still missing the name of the assembly for your second connection string resource and should change it to res://*/MyDb.csdl. This explains why you didn't see it with dotpeek. You can also use ildasm or reflector to double check they are there
